# Recommended Eclipse Plugins for development with OpenLayers and GeoExt?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, plugins, eclipse

we plan to create an map oriented online application and muse about the 'best' / helpful plugins for Eclipse.
The used technology is OpenLayers and GeoExt.

For example is the Javascript development tools (JSDT) helpful?
Or - are there any other tools, not necessarily Eclipse plugins, which help during development?

Can you share your experiences?

D3

Comment: I am using Aptana Studio for details check this http://geographika.co.uk/openlayers-and-versioning-in-aptana-studio

Comment: We didn't find any OpenLayers Specific plugins or tools. You should base your decision on Core JavaScript tooling support. Also do look into Jetbrains' Webstorm. I found it to be miles above any other IDE.

Comment: I also reccomend you Webstorm, it's way faster than any eclipse-based IDE, and has a very good context help. If OpenLayers is in the project, it will index the functions and give you some hints with the context-help

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing server side code in Java, I'd recommend IntelliJ (also by JetBrains) or Netbeans. They both handle javascript pretty well.

If you're not doing serverside code or serverside with node.js,  I think Webstorm is a good option. I'd also consider a simpler tool, like Sublime Text, that has very good plug-ins supporting javascript development.